# apache vhost config - why doesn't this work

Tags: apache-2.2

I have an ubuntu with the the following config file:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName dev.domain.com
    DocumentRoot /data/sites/dev.domain.com/www/public
</VirtualHost>
```

Other vhost files are being served correctly on this host. It is properly symlinked; the directory exists. Is there a reason why this is not working? I don't see anything in the standard apache server logs.

thx

edit:
this is an ubuntu host and many other vhosts using the standard sites-available / sites-enabled are working. One issue is that it runs both mod_php and phusion mod_rails.

@Lain here's the output from a2ensite:
jon@ve:/etc/apache2/sites-available$ sudo sudo a2ensite /etc/apache2/apache2.conf
ERROR: No site found matching /etc/apache2/apache2.conf!

here's the output from apache2ctl -S (thx for this - I had always wondered how to to do this)

```
 jon@ve:/etc/apache2/sites-available$ /usr/sbin/apache2ctl -S
 VirtualHost configuration:
 wildcard NameVirtualHosts and _default_ servers:
*:80                   is a NameVirtualHost
         default server ve.vesrv.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default:1)
         port 80 namevhost ve.vesrv.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default:1)
         port 80 namevhost testfb.hex.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/001-testfb:1)
         port 80 namevhost testfb2.hex.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/002-testfb2:1)
    ....
         port 80 namevhost rails-dev.rtm.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/018-rails-dev.rtm.com:1)
         port 80 namevhost dev.domain.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/019-dev.domain.com:6)
Syntax OK
jon@ve:/etc/apache2/sites-available$
```

Comment: Is this your entire virtualhost container?  Take a look at some of the other working vhosts, you are missing the location container.

Comment: What happens when you attempt to access `dev.domain.com`. Show us the output of `/usr/sbin/apache2ctl -S`.

Comment: If you don't see ANYTHING in your logs, are you sure that `dev.domain.com` has that server's IP?

Answer (score 1):

Add to the file, between `<VirtualHost>...</VirtualHost>`:

```
<Directory /data/sites/dev.domain.com/www/public>
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
</Directory>
```

Make sure you have `NameVirtualHost *:80` somewhere before this file is loaded. (You can stick it just before `<VirtualHost *:80>` to be sure.)

**EDIT 2:** Make sure you `sudo a2ensite config_file`  **config_file is the file that contains the `<VirtualHost>` block. Should be `/etc/apache2/sites-available/dev.domain.com.conf` and you should use `sudo a2ensite dev.domain.com.conf`**

Make sure you `sudo apahce2ctl restart`

EDIT:

Regarding logs, not sure what your global conf is. You may need this within `<VirtualHost>...</VirtualHost>`:

```
    ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/dev.domain.com-error.log

    # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
    # alert, emerg.
    LogLevel warn

    CustomLog /var/log/apache2/dev.domain.com-access.log combined
```

Answer (score 0):

If you really have created a vhost called `dev.domain.com` then unless you have created your own DNS entry for it, it will not be resolving to your server so you won't see anything. It seems unlikely that you are the owner of `domain.com` so it's a not a good idea to be creating vhosts and DNS entries for it's sub domains yourself. Better to create a vhost and DNS entries for a domain that you control.

Comment: a DNS record has been created and it resolves correctly. It's currently showing the default apache site implying that there's something wrong with the apache configuration

Comment: Did you try a full restart `sudo apache2ctl restart` ?

Comment: yep, restarted, rebooted computer, everything... sorry, I know this is probably something REALLY stupid. I think it might be something with phusion passenger